# Split string into array by several delimiters

Tags: javascript, arrays

Folks,
  I have looked at underscore.string and string.js modules and still can't find a good way to do the following:

Suppose I have a query string string:

```
"!dogs,cats,horses!cows!fish"
```

I would like to pass it to a function that looks for all words that start with `!`, and get back an Array:

```
['dogs','cows','fish']
```

Similarly, the same function should return an array of words that start with `,`:

```
['cats','horses]
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: you could `split` multiple times. a regex might be better tho.

Comment: Do you want multiple arrays, or just one?

Comment: yup ^^ `str.split('!').split(',')` will return an array of arrays. do you mean that you _must_ use underscore?

Comment: dont have to use underscore at all...

Comment: @DanielA.White split will leave out the ,

Comment: @jtmarmon `str.split()` returns an array, which does not have the `split` method. You'd get a `TypeError` with that.

Comment: my mistake. the equivalent of what i was trying to do would be `var items = str.split('!').map(function(str2) {return str2.split(',');}_` which would return a single-level array

Comment: @jtmarmon so will that work for `!dogs,cats!horses` will return `['dogs',horses']` ?

Comment: i wouldnt mind getting back 2 arrays, one with words that are prefixed with `!`, other with `,`

Comment: no, if you want only the first item between `!` you would do `var items = str.split('!').map(function(str2) {return str2.split(',')[0];})`

Comment: @jtmarmon not the first item, all of them... sry.... ie `cats,horses,!dogs,!fish,birds` should return `['dogs','fish']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx to easily match the split characters.

```
var string = "!dogs,cats,horses!cows!fish";
var splitString = string.split(/!|,/);
// ["dogs", "cats", "horses", "cows", "fish"]
```

The only issue with that is that it will possibly add an empty string at the beginning of the array if you start it with `!`. You could fix that with a function:

```
splitString.forEach(function(item){ 
    if(item === ""){ 
    splitString.splice(splitString.indexOf(item), 1)
    } 
  });
```

**EDIT**:

In response to your clarificaiton, here is a function that does as you ask. It currently returns an object with the values `commas` and `exclaim`, each with an array of the corresponding elements.

[JSBin showing it working.](http://jsbin.com/lutihay/1/edit?js,console)

```
function splitString(str){

  var exclaimValues = [];
  var expandedValues = [];
  var commaValues    = [];
  var needsUnshift = false;

  //First split the comma delimited values
  var stringFragments = str.split(',');

  //Iterate through them and see if they contain ! 
  for(var i = 0; i < stringFragments.length; i++){

    var stringValue = stringFragments[i];

    // if the value contains an !, its an exclaimValue
    if (stringValue.indexOf('!') !== -1){
      exclaimValues.push(stringValue);
    } 

    // otherwise, it's a comma value
    else {
      commaValues.push(stringValue);
    }
  }

  // iterate through each exclaim value
  for(var i = 0; i < exclaimValues.length; i++){

       var exclaimValue = exclaimValues[i]; 
       var expandedExclaimValues = exclaimValue.split('!');

        //we know that if it doesn't start with !, the 
        // the first value is actually a comma value. So move it

       if(exclaimValue.indexOf('!') !== 0) commaValues.unshift(expandedExclaimValues.shift());



    for(var j = 0; j < expandedExclaimValues.length; j++){
      var expandedExclaimValue = expandedExclaimValues[j];

       //If it's not a blank entry, push it to our results list.
      if(expandedExclaimValue  !== "") expandedValues.push(expandedExclaimValue);     
    }               
  }

  return {comma: commaValues, exclaim: expandedValues};

}
```

So if we do:

```
var str = "!dogs,cats,horses!cows!fish,comma!exclaim,comma2,comma3!exclaim2";
var results = splitString(str)
```

`results` would be:

```
{
  comma: ["comma3", "comma", "horses", "cats", "comma2"],
  exclaim: ["dogs", "cows", "fish", "exclaim", "exclaim2"]
}
```

Comment: yes, thats easy.  however, im trying to accomplish returning just the strings I asked for, ie words that `just` start with `!` and strip out the ones that start with `,`

Comment: Hey @Cmag, I wrote a function that accomplishes what you're looking for. See my edit for the details.